# What is the difference between the terms ‘basic’ and ‘fundamental’?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, meaning-in-context, differences, synonyms

I am reading an article titled “Basic needs, basic rights” in which the author emphasises on the need of a robust doctrine of basic rights in addition to fundamental rights.

Source: 
https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/basic-needs-basic-rights/article28128689.ece/amp/

Comment: You need to read it carefully to determine what the author is saying. Provide a link if you want someone here to figure it out for you.

Comment: Hi Xanne, have provided the link in the question body now.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic rights** is the common/day-to-day usage word for human rights. Therefore basic/human rights are universally acclaimed and are provided to everyone living on Earth, no matter in which country they live. You can thus say **these rights are universally absolute and meant for everyone regardless of the nation they belong.**

**Fundamental rights are solely the rights granted to a citizen of that particular country.** Any rights you gain or any duties you owe are constitutionally provided. So there are different fundamentals rights in different countries. Countries also provide some basic human rights to there citizens as a part of their fundamental rights.

*For example:*

> Right to live is a basic right and no country can legally deny it.
>
> Right to follow any religion publicly and freely is a fundamental
>   right in countries like US, UK, Canada, India, Japan, etc. But aren't a
>   fundamental right in countries like Iran, Pakistan, Myanmar etc.
>
> So, if the government of Myanmar is killing Muslim they aren't
>   violating the Fundamental rights of Myanmar because according to them
>   it's based on religion which isn't free. But because they are killing
>   people (no matter which religion they follow), they are violating the
>   Human rights (commonly known a basic rights).

**Also, there are countries which include some human rights in their constitution and thus make that it both fundamental right and human right.**

*For example:*

> Right to healthy, unpolluted environment is a basic human right but also a
>   fundamental right in countries like Japan. So, if it is violated in
>   Japan then both fundamental rights and human/basic rights are
>   violated.

*I just read the article you linked. It's in regard of 'The right to provide accessible healthcare'. The journalist is emphasising that this right should be incorporated in Indian constitution as it is a very basic thing (like air, food and water) in 2019. It isn't a human right or fundamental right in India but according to him it should be and failing which should guarantee a major punishment by the government.*

*Hope it helped...*